# Set a marker from point A to point B in MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, shortcut

I have over 90k lines of data and sometimes when i want to execute queries i dont want to highlight everything, let's say for example i just want to highlight from line 1 to line 30k then execute those lines. Is there any shortcut on how to do that? Right now i am using my mouse to highlight from line 1 to line 30k and it takes very long time.

Comment: "execute those lines" - what does that mean? How can you execute "lines" of data?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel it means running the codes by pressing the "thunder" button. Its in mysql workbench